# Deleting ECS services with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, yaml, amazon-ecs

I am trying to delete four ECS services with Ansible 2.9.13. I know Ansible can't delete ECS services with running tasks, so I tried setting desired_count to "0" and then deleting it:

```
- name: Set Service Tasks to 0
  ecs_service:
    name:  "{{service}}"
    state: present
    desired_count: 0
    cluster:  "{{cluster_name}}"
    task_definition: "{{service_data.services[0].taskDefinition}}"
    region: "{{region}}"

- name: Delete OLD ECS service
  ecs_service:
    state: absent
    name:  "{{service}}"
    cluster:  "{{cluster_name}}"
    region: "{{region}}"
```

It worked for the first service but failed on the second one with this error:

```
"msg": "It is not possible to update the load balancers of an existing service"
```

Has anyone run across this issue? Any suggestions on getting around it?

Comment: A bit of Google-Fu said that the container port integer is sometimes read as a string. I specified that by getting the info an adding it back to the code as `containerPort: "{{service_data.services[0].loadBalancers[0].containerPort | int}}"` but I still get the same error. :(

Comment: Hi, first remove the ALB rule, then the Target group, then the AWS ECS service.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured it out. It kept thinking I'm trying to change the load balancer, but I was not. No idea why. So I opted to grab all the ALB info and just feed it to the module directly. That did the trick.

Since only two out of the four services actually have a load balancer, this posed another problem. It would fail on the ones WITHOUT. Got around that by adding a conditional. So here's the final mess:

```
- name: Get Service Data
  ecs_service_info:
    cluster: "{{cluster_name}}"
    region: "{{region}}"
    service: "{{service}}"
    details: true
  register: service_data

- set_fact: with_lb=true
  when: service_data.services[0].loadBalancers|length == 1

- set_fact: with_lb=false
  when: service_data.services[0].loadBalancers|length == 0

- name: Set Tasks with ALB to 0
  ecs_service:
    name: "{{service}}"
    state: present
    desired_count: 0
    cluster: "{{cluster_name}}"
    load_balancers:
      - containerPort: "{{service_data.services[0].loadBalancers[0].containerPort | int}}"
        containerName: "{{service_data.services[0].loadBalancers[0].containerName}}"
        targetGroupArn: "{{service_data.services[0].loadBalancers[0].targetGroupArn}}"
    task_definition: "{{service_data.services[0].taskDefinition}}"
    region: "{{region}}"
  when: with_lb|bool

- name: Set Remaining Tasks to 0
  ecs_service:
    name: "{{service}}"
    state: present
    desired_count: 0
    cluster: "{{cluster_name}}"
    task_definition: "{{service_data.services[0].taskDefinition}}"
    region: "{{region}}"
  when: not with_lb|bool

- name: Delete OLD ECS service
  ecs_service:
    state: absent
    name:  "{{service}}"
    cluster:  "{{cluster_name}}"
    region: "{{region}}"
```

Cheers!